# Bootstrap multiple bars on horizontal progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone knows how to come up with a bar like this on Bootstrap?

[image: progrees bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roonie007/4db788mq/)

```
div
{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
      transparent, transparent .25em /* black stripe */, 
      #EA9949 0, #EA9949 .75em /* blue stripe */
    );
}
```

**Update**

here is how to make it works [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roonie007/4db788mq/3/)

```
function setProgressbarValue(currentValue,MaxValue)
{
    var percentage = ((currentValue/MaxValue) * 100) ;
    if (percentage <= 0)
        percentage = 0;
    else if (percentage >= 100)
        percentage = 100;
    return parseInt(percentage);
}
```

Comment: that's great Diptox.  But how do i create something so that it is processive? like starting from on bar, second bar, third... depending on the data from the Database.

Comment: Thanks. Just what i was looking for.